# line 26, in __init__ tk.Tk().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs). TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not App

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem here is that I get an error saying:
line 26, in **init**     tk.Tk().**init**(self, *args, **kwargs).
TypeError: create() argument 1 must be str or None, not App.
I have never dealt with this kind of error before does anyone know how to solve this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk



class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side='top',fill="both",expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight =1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        

        tk.Frame.title('Simulator')
        self.geometry("800x800")
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self, text='Sim',font=("Calibri",28,"bold"))


        self.label0 = ttk.Label(self,font=("Calibri",24,"bold"), text='Monkey')
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self,font=("Calibri",24,"bold"), text='Giraffe')
        self.label2 = ttk.Label(self, text="Flat border", font=("Calibri",24,"bold"), relief="flat")

       

        

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    App = App()
    App.mainloop()
    time_hours(5)
```

Comment: This line is wrong `tk.Tk().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: First `App` should be inherited from `tk.Tk` instead of `tk.Frame`.  Second `tk.Tk().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` should be `tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`.  Also `tk.Frame.title('Simulator')` should be `self.title('Simulator')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

- `App` should be inherited from `tk.Tk` instead of `tk.Frame`
- `tk.Tk().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` should be `tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`, or `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`
- `tk.Frame.title('Simulator')` should be `self.title('Simulator')`
- `self.simulation += [Monkey(), Giraffe, Elephant()]` should be `self.simulation += [Monkey(), Giraffe(), Elephant()]`, I think
- need to add `from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo`

Comment: you are correct my program now works thank you very much kind Sir.